# Conditional Formatting in Excel Based on Drop Down Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need solution: (Unable to find in group based on below example)

Format cell color based on drop down.

Example

If A1 Drop down value 'Shirt' then color A2, A5 and A6 as yellow.

If A1 Drop down value 'Tie' then color A3, A7 and A9 as green.

User has to fill the highlighted columns if they select the value as Shirt or Tie.

Comment: What is the logic behind those being highlighted, are they specific cells, or does the color also depend on the value in those target cells?  Remember we can not see your data.

Comment: That seems like conditional formatting based on a formula and you have the formula to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two rules with formula:

- First:

  - Applies To: `=$A$2,$A$5:$A$6`
  - Formula:    `=$A$1="Shirt"`
- Second:

  - Applies To: `=$A$3,$A$7,$A$9`
  - Formula:    `=$A$1="Tie"`

[image]

[image]